# 400 (Bad Request) in Axios and react js

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, request

I need to send post request contin image and title and description so when send request, I get bad request error

```
 const handlePostRequest = async (imageFile, title, text) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", imageFile);
    formData.append("title", title);
    formData.append("text", text);
    await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url:  "https://oceansworlds-19029-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/worldoceans.json",
        formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `firebase` is responding:

```
400 Bad Request:
error: Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value.
```

1. Replace `formData` by `data` in `axios` params.
2. `stringify` your data before the request.

```js
const handlePostRequest = async (imageFile, title, text) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", imageFile);
    formData.append("title", title);
    formData.append("text", text);

    await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url:  "https://oceansworlds-19029-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/worldoceans.json",
        data: JSON.stringify(formData), // <---- here
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })}
```

Comment: Not Working  the same error